# Apply the same operations on several dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with around 30 equally-looking csv files in Pandas (one-minute timeseries data, one year each, ~100 MB). Mostly, I do the same operation on each of the 30 dataframes. Is there a convenient way to apply an operation on each of the dataframes at once but keeping the files separately? Something like this?

```
for df in df1,df2,df3:
    df=df.dropna(subset=['A','B'])
    df['C'] = df['A']/df['B'] 
    df_a = df[(df.C >= 50)]
```

Comment: `for file in file_list: df = pd.read_csv(file);...`?

Comment: you overwrite `df_a` in the last line of you loop in each iteration - is this a typo?

Comment: Actually it isnt. Apart from the filtering I also want to create smaller sub-dataframes from the main dataframe based on some filtering....is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

- The files can be manipulated or filtered as you need and then stored in a dictionary for review
- Each new dataframe is a value in the dictionary
- Use `pathlib` to find all the files
- Treats file names and paths as objects with methods

  - `.stem` gets the file name, which can be used as part of the `key` for the stored dataframes

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

p = Path('csv_files/Data/')  # path to files
files = list(p.glob('*.csv'))  # list of files

df_dict = dict()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)  # create dataframe from file
    df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
    df['C'] = df['A'] / df['B']
    key = f'filtered_{file.stem}'
    df_dict[key] = df[(df.C >= 50)]  # create a new dataframe and store it in a dictionary
    
    
# get list of keys
print(df_dict.keys())

# access a dataframe
df_dict['filtered_file_name']

# save dataframes
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv')
```

#### f-strings

- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

#### pathlib

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library.
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally got round to implementing it. It kind of works. I just don't quite get what the line `key = f'filtered_{file.stem}'` does. There is only the (alphabetically) last file stored in the key variable ....same happens if I call  `df_dict[key]`...

Comment: @N.Foe `file` is the entire path and filename. `file.stem` returns the file name only. `key = f'filtered_{file.stem}'` is an f-string that creates a string `filtered_filename` which is then used as a dictionary key. _There is only the (alphabetically) last file stored in the key variable_ that's correct each key holds the filtered data for that file. You stated _but keeping the files separately_, so this code performs the operation on the file and keeps the result separate.